# Zoneminder homepage not loading

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up Zoneminder using [this tutorial](http://tuxradar.com/content/build-your-own-surveillance-zoneminder#null).

I've started with even installing Ubuntu Server (14.04), so it's a fresh install.

The first problem I came across might be relevant, so I'll mention it first: conf.d didn't exist, so the line

```
sudo ln -s /etc/zm/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/zoneminder.conf
```

didn't work for me.  I just used mkdir to create the conf.d directory, based on something I read online.  This might be what's causing the problem (in which case, I still don't know how to fix it).

But I came to the first show-stopper problem at the part that says to go to "zm" in the browser (in my case, 192.168.1.155).  The Apache "It works" test page works fine, but 192.168.1.155/zm, it returns a 404 error.

Any idea on how to fix it?  I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling php5-common.  (And I also reinstalled Zoneminder, of course, because php5-common is a dependency.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [files in the apache2 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/apache2/filelist), `/etc/apache2/conf.d` is not the right directory. You'd want the symlink to ultimately be in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.